# How to assign Ctrl+, (control plus comma) as the keyboard shortcut to a WPF menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

**Question**

I would like to assign the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (control plus comma) to the "Preferences..." menu item. How do I do that?

There is a `Key.OemComma` in the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx) enumeration. I have used `Key.OemComma` as shown in the code sample below. That works fine functionality-wise. But GUI-wise: the menu item is displayed as

- Preferences (Ctrl+OemComma)

instead of

- Preferences (Ctrl+,)

**Sample Code**

```
InputGestureCollection keyInputs = new InputGestureCollection();
keyInputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.OemComma, ModifierKeys.Control));
preferencesCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Preferences...", "Preferences", typeof(MyCommands), keyInputs);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the [KeyGesture constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa345788.aspx) that takes a display string would work. You could call it like this:

```
InputGestureCollection keyInputs = new InputGestureCollection();
keyInputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.OemComma, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+,"));
preferencesCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Preferences...", "Preferences", typeof(MyCommands), keyInputs);
```